# Unconfigured tmux status bar cut off by two characters

Tags: tmux

My tmux status bar line appears cut off by two characters, even with nothing in my `~/.tmux.conf`. The last two digits of the year are missing. How do you fix this? I've tried different fonts with the same result each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me `tmux show-option -g status-right` yields:

```
status-right " \"#{=21:pane_title}\" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
```

And the status is like  `"foobar" 21:10 07-Jan-20`. `%y` expands to `20` because of 20**20**. It's not **20**20 with the two last digits missing. One year ago it would be `19` because of 20**19**.

To see all digits use `%Y`:

```
tmux set-option -g status-right " \"#{=21:pane_title}\" %H:%M %d-%b-%Y"
```

For a permanent solution, add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g status-right " \"#{=21:pane_title}\" %H:%M %d-%b-%Y"
```

---

Relevant parts of `man 3 strftime` (because `man 1 tmux` refers to `strftime(3)`):

> `%y` The year as a decimal number without a century (range `00` to `99`). […]
>
> `%Y` The year as a decimal number including the century. […]

Answer (score 1):

The status on the left and right side of the bars have a maximum length. The default size of the right hand size is 40 characters. You can adjust it inside your .tmux.conf file.

```
set -g status-right-length 42
```